# Flutter sum amount with quantity

Tags: flutter, dart

I have some array I need to calculate the amount. This is also done but there is one issue I want ammo use to multiply also mean if the array has quantity 2 then amount first multiply by 2 then add.

My code

```
allRows.forEach((row) {
  amount += double.parse(row['price']);
  //print(amount);
});
```

Row look like this

```
{uId: 5116, id: 1195, quantity: 2,price: 2}
{uId: 5116, id: 1195, quantity: 1,price: 3}
```

Right now it's showing 5 but I need to result 7.

Comment: So just add _quantity times_ price... think about how you would do this on pencil and paper, then translate that to code. So, just `amount += double.parse(row['quantity']) * double.parse(row['price'])`

Answer (score 0):

```dart
allRows.forEach((row) {
  amount += double.parse(row['quantity']) * double.parse(row['price']);
});
```

Comment: I'd think it best to assume `quantity` can be decimal, so make it `double`.